# Refactoring rails model to remove string literals from condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring

I get a warning every time I start my server that I have string literals in my conditions. What does this mean, and how can I improve my code to fix this and stop getting the warning?

```
  def partner_cars
    if self.role == 'Garage Employee' || self.role == 'Garage Manager'
      self.cars
    elsif self.role == 'Company Employee' || 'Company Manager'
      self.company.cars
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def partner_users
    if self.role == 'Garage Employee' || self.role == 'Garage Manager'
      allowed_users = self.users
    elsif self.role == 'Company Employee' || 'Company Manager'
      allowed_users = self.company.users
    else
      allowed_users = nil
    end
    allowed_users.uniq
  end
```

Any help on how to refactor this code would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the line `elsif self.role == 'Company Employee' || 'Company Manager'`. Instead, it should be `elsif self.role == 'Company Employee' || self.role == 'Company Manager'`.

However, I would refactor your code to use `case` statements like this:

```
def partner_cars
  case role
    when 'Garage Employee', 'Garage Manager' then cars
    when 'Company Employee', 'Company Manager' then company.cars
  end
end

def partner_users
  allowed_users =
    case role
      when 'Garage Employee', 'Garage Manager' then users
      when 'Company Employee', 'Company Manager' then company.users
    end
  allowed_users.try(:uniq)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your data structure, its hard to suggest a refactoring approach.

```
def partner_cars
  if garage_roles.include?(self.role)
    ...some code
  elsif employee_roles.include?(self.role)
    ..some code
  end
end

private
def garage_roles
  ['Garage Employee', 'Garage Manager']
end
```

Even better would be to set up these methods in your role model.

```
class Role
  def works_for_garage?
    title == 'Garage Manager' || 'Garage Employee'
  end
end
```